How to find water leak source?
The laminate floor next to the shower started to get "squishy" as soon as we started using it and is now warped. We've been told to fix the leak, we need to replace the shower pan. Someone went in the crawl space and saw no further water damage.
How do we confirm the source of the leak and what fixes are needed? Currently we believe we need to demo the floor and bottom part of shower wall tiles,replace the shower pan and the drain (it also looks poorly installed).
Was hoping for confirmation this is the solution from this group. thx!


You spoke of the laminate floor next to the shower, but showed a pic of the shower floor. Is your question about replacing the shower floor?  If the floor outside the shower is "squishy", you have a serious problem that requires much more than the shower floor to be repaired. Also I saw no laminate flooring in your pic. Are you sure about what flooring you have?

HI @RMDman thanks for your reply. We think the leak is coming from a poorly installed shower pan. The laminate floor isn't squishy anymore once we stopped using the shower. I'm adding a picture of what it looks like now: there is some spacing between "planks" which im ok with if that's just an aesthetic problem.

The second picture shows serious signs of water infiltration in the base of the wall and floor.  I stand by my original comment. The shower floor may need repaired, but the damage may extend farther beyond the base of the shower.  This is something that needs to be approached with an open mind, until the extent of the water damage is known.

Understood, thanks @RMDman. What's the best way for us to understand the extent of the water damage? Hire a plumber or general contractor?

You need a CG to dismantle the shower and find the extent of the damage. Then ask for a plan and estimate to do the repairs.  You will need to pay for the shower demo to get a good idea of what the cost is. This is one of the times the cost could be X or 3 times x, depending on what is found.
